# Perl - Difference between next and redo

Tags: perl

When I am executing a program both giving the same result. Please explain the difference between 'next' & 'redo'.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/continue.html

Comment: @AruneshSingh - Please don't post links to pirate copies of books. You open up StackOverflow to being sued for piracy. Please delete your comment.

Comment: @Dave Cross, Re "You open up StackOverflow to being sued for piracy.", No, he didn't. SO is not guilty of the actions of others. SO would not be sued; SO would be given a DMCA takedown request. He shouldn't post the link for many other reasons, but that's not one of them.

Comment: Ok. Fair point. It's been removed anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`redo`, `next` and `last` are used inside *loop blocks* in Perl. Most often you will see them in `for` or `while` blocks, but you can use them in a bare block if you need to

The essential difference is

- `redo` jumps to the *beginning* of the block -- the opening brace `{`
- `next` jumps to the *end* of the block -- the closing brace `}`
- `last` jumps out of the block altogether

`next` and `last` are only different for the blocks of `while` and `for` loops (and for blocks that have a `continue` section)

So you could write a loop like this

```
my $n;
{
    ++$n;
    print $n, "\n";
    redo if $n < 10;
}
```

which would print the numbers from 1 to 10

Answer (score 14):

```
for (1 .. 9) {
    next if $_ % 2;
    print;
}
```

prints "2468" because every time `$_` is an odd number, `next` jumps out of the loop and continues with the next number.

```
for (1 .. 9) {
    redo if $_ % 2;
    print;
}
```

loops forever and prints nothing because 1 is odd, so `redo` jumps back to the beginning of the loop body *without advancing the loop*, so `$_` stays 1 and nothing ever happens.

- `next` will advance to the next item in a `foreach` loop; `redo` won't.
- `next` will run the increment (middle) statement in a C-style `for` loop; `redo` won't.
- `next` will re-check the condition in a `while` loop or C-style `for` loop; `redo` won't.
- `next` will exit a bare loop (`{ ... }`); `redo` will restart it.
- `next` will run a `continue` block; `redo` won't.

Semantically, `next` finishes the current iteration and then does whatever happens *after*. `redo` runs all of the code for the current iteration *over again*. `next` is like jumping to the *bottom* of the block (in fact, if you use it in a block that's not a loop, it will just jump to the end), and `redo` is like jumping to the *top* of the block (in fact, you can use `redo` to make a loop... `{ print "Hello"; redo }` is equivalent to `while (1) { print "Hello" }`.

Comment: Re my edit: Oh, you had mentioned it, but only later in your answer?!? Not sure why. Adjust as you want.

Answer (score 3):

**Next**-Program Execution continues with the next iteration of the loop.It is like `continue` operator in C.Next keyword is use to skip the code in the rest of the loop if some condition is met.

**Redo**-It makes program execution to go back to the top of the current loop, without testing any conditional expression or advancing to the next iteration.

For Example,

In case of next

```
foreach (split){
    next;   ## next comes here ##
            # statements are skipped
}
```

In case of Redo

```
    LOOPLABEL:
        {
           $count++;
           redo LOOPLABEL if ($count < 3);
           #Does not advance to the next iteration        
        }
```

The main difference between next and redo is that next will advance to the next iteration by reevaluating a condition, but redo will redo the current iteration starting execution from topmost statement in a loop.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can give some example or more explanation about _'next will advance to the next iteration, but redo will redo the current iteration'_.

Answer (score 3):

**next**:
The *next* keyword lets you skip the rest of the statement block and start the next iteration. One use of this behavior could be to select specific array elements for processing and ignoring the rest.

For example:

```
my @array = (0..9);
print "@array\n";
for (my $index = 0; $index < @array; $index++)
{
    if ($index == 3 || $index == 5)
    {
        next;
    }
    $array[$index] = "*";
}
print "@array\n";
```

Above example changes every array element, except the 3rd and 5th, to asterisks regardless of their former value. The *next* keyword forces Perl to skip over the assignment statement and go directly to the increment/decrement expression. You can also use the *next* keyword in nested loops.

**redo**:
The *redo* keyword causes Perl to restart the current statement block. Neither the increment/decrement expression nor the conditional expression is evaluated before restarting the block. This keyword is usually used when getting input from outside the program, either from the keyboard or from a file. It is essential that the conditions that caused the *redo* statement to execute can be changed so that an endless loop does not occur.

For example:

```
{   #start a statement block 
    print "What is your name?\n";
    my $name = <STDIN>;
    chop($name);

    if (! length($name))
    {
        print "Zero length input. Please try again\n";
        redo;
    }

    print "Thank you, " . $name, "\n";
}
```

It's worth noting that the statement block in *redo* example acts like a single-time loop construct.

Comment: Your `redo` example will not work because it is not within a block.

Comment: @dgw the braces on the very first and last lines of the example form a "bare block" - a loop that executes exactly once, unless modified by a control keyword. This is the loop that the `redo` operates on.